# Coilgun troubles

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I am trying to make a coil gun and I'm following a design made by Mehdi Sadaghdar the link is below.

http://www.electroboom.com/?p=101

I am having trouble with my IRF540N nmos transistor. At first I did not know that the device was polarity sensitive and it conducted every time I put power to it. This makes me think it may already be broken. After realising it was the wrong way round I turned it around only to have it conduct from the drain through the gate to ground on my low voltage side of the circuit (There was a small puff of smoke when this happened so I'm sure the device is dead now). The transistor I'm talking about is labelled Q1.

This is the circuit diagram I created. It is very similar to Mehdi's but I have lower voltages at V1 and V2.

[image: My circuit]

I know my connections aren't exactly nasa level but this is what I've done

[image]

I am unsure why my transistor is behaving like this so if anyone could help out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain the connections to your transistor are correct? That transistor has the pinout gate|drain|source when looking at it from the front (so the metal tab is at the back)

Comment: What does the photo transistor do?

Comment: detect when the ball passed

Comment: After the puff of "magic" smoke, did you try a new FET?  (WAG is that you damaged the FET when you put it in backwards.)  Is D1 in the correct way?  How big a diode is it?

Comment: @skyrift 

I'm sorry I'm a little unsure on how this comment system works right now so if I make a mistake I'm sorry in advance.

I'm confident I have the pinout of my transistor correct now but I'm thinking George might be correct when saying it might already broken. Also the diode is a MBR735 II35A and I'm pretty confident the diode is around the right way as well. I think it will be best buying a fresh transistor and testing that one.